# jar from Eclipse, maven, spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I'm using sts to write some applications. Now what i need to do is create jar file from this projects. But i don't want to export using eclipse option. I need to write script that will build it when I deploy my main (server) app using jenkins.

So I need to write script that will build jar file, and really don't have idea how to do this. Don't know how to get all jars which i add to pom file. And without this i can't build jar using javac.

I was trying to find answer on that question but with no success.

Please help.

Comment: Using this below link you can get basic idea about Jenkins. It's contains all  basic concept about Jenkins.     [1]: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ywIMAHR42ETqkzHAK1FJJa_c6uwLWtytRx8TBD9oi_4/edit#slide=id.gea8b2dd_1_15

Comment: You mentioned "maven" and "pom.xml" - do have have some knowledge about maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use maven-shade-plugin plugin. Here is what I used for one of my Spring, Hibernate, Maven based project.

add this to your plugins list and this will build you a jar file in the target folder when you build you project i.e. the package phase.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>your-jar-filename</finalName>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.project.main.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```